# grouping / order by in sqlalchemy query

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

This group by / order by wont work, the point is to count `HTTP.statusline` on minute and then return it. Now it return multiple time of minute. In the database the date is saved as String.

Example on output:

```
{u'date': u'2013-03-12 11:23:48', u'count': 21}
```

but something is returning more then one value like this:

```
{u'date': u'2013-03-12 11:36:21', u'count': 2}, {u'date': u'2013-03-12 11:36:21', u'count': 8}]
```

Code:

```
def statusline_date(status):
    session = load_session()
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    DD = now - datetime.timedelta(minutes=60)
    DD = DD.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    #query = session.query(HTTP.date, extract('minute', HTTP.date).label('min'), HTTP.statusline, func.count(HTTP.statusline).
    #        label('count')).filter(HTTP.statusline.like('%'+status+'%'), HTTP.date>=(DD+'%')).group_by('min').all()
    query = session.query(HTTP.date, HTTP.statusline, func.count(HTTP.statusline).
            label('count')).filter(HTTP.statusline.like('%'+status+'%'), HTTP.date>=(DD)).group_by(HTTP.date, HTTP.statusline).order_by(asc(HTTP.date)).all()

    result = [{'date': t.date, 'count': t.count} for t in query]

    return result
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are grouping on both the date and the status line; most likely the status line differs between the two results.

Either include that status line in your output, or remove it from the group and output columns altogether.

Including the status line:

```
result = [{'date': t.date, 'count': t.count, 'status': t.statusline} for t in query]
```

would show what differs.

Removing the column from the group and columns list:

```
query = session.query(HTTP.date, func.count(HTTP.statusline).
        label('count')).filter(HTTP.statusline.like('%'+status+'%'), HTTP.date>=(DD)).group_by(HTTP.date).order_by(asc(HTTP.date)).all()
```

Instead of `.like('%'+status+'%')`, you could also use [`.contains(status)`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.contains); it is usually *implemented* as a LIKE but you don't have to do the `%` concatenation yourself.